Apex Class not working in Prod. Works great in Sandbox
I am really new to Apex, so I apologize if this has been asked/answered.  I created an Apex class for a flow in the Sandbox.  It was working great, when I used the outbound change set to move it to prod, the validation failed.  Following are the 2 messages:

CGMC_SOD_AuditChangeAlert_Test    testNotification    System.AssertException:
Assertion Failed Stack Trace:
Class.CGMC_SOD_AuditChangeAlert_Test.testNotification: line 9, column
1
OppUpdateResigned updateAccount   System.DmlException: Insert failed.
First exception on row 0; first error:
FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Specify a Closed Lost Reason: []
Stack Trace: Class.OppUpdateResigned.setup: line 17, column 1

And here is the code I used:
public class AutoConvertLeads {
   @InvocableMethod   
    public static void LeadAssign(List<Id> LeadIds)  
    {
        LeadStatus CLeadStatus= [SELECT ID, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true Limit 1];
        List<Database.LeadConvert> MassLeadconvert = new List <Database.LeadConvert>();
             for(id currentlead: LeadIds){
                DATABASE.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new DATABASE.LeadConvert(); 
                Leadconvert.setLeadId(currentlead);                               
                Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(CLeadStatus.MasterLabel);             
                Leadconvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(FALSE); 
                MassLeadconvert.add(Leadconvert); 
        }
       IF (!MassLeadconvert.isEmpty())
       {
       List<DATABASE.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(MassLeadconvert);    
        }
 
    }   
}

Could someone help me with where i've gone wrong?  Thank you!!

There is clearly a validation rule or similar on production you do not have on your sandbox. Update the unit test so it defines data that will pass the validation rule, on the sandbox, even if you don't have it on the sandbox. That way when you promote to production the unit test won't fail.
Do what the error message says and set a reason in the data used by the test.

Thank you for your help!  This is the only error I still have and can't figure out how to bypass it.  Any suggestions?    CGMC_SOD_AuditChangeAlert_Test testNotification System.AssertException: Assertion Failed
Stack Trace: Class.CGMC_SOD_AuditChangeAlert_Test.testNotification: line 9, column 1

The test is asserting a condition; look at the testNotification method, line 9. It expects something to happen, but it does not. Again, this could be due to some validation rule or similar, but probably the code somewhere has a try/catch that hides the issue. You will need to work your way through what the tested code does and look for places this might happen.
